# TypeScript using "this" keyword in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I'm working on a custom interface where I'd like to be able to infer the type of an interface value in its implementation, rather than in the interface definition, without generics. I should add that these implementations will always be object literals and not classes.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Defintion {
  params: unknown; // Should resolve to the type in the implementation
  handler: (dummy: this["params"]) => void; // I want `this` to refer to the implementation, not the interface
}


const customDefn: Defintion = {
  params: { test: "Hello World" },
  handler: (dummy) => {
    // TS Complains here
    console.log(dummy.test)
  }
}
```

What I want to happen is the type of `customDefn.params` to resolve to `{ test: "Hello World" }` (so I can get autocomplete in `handler`) rather than remaining as `unknown`.

I am aware I can use generics:

```
interface Defintion<T> {
  params: T;
  handler: (dummy: this["params"]) => void;
}
```

However, I would then have to define `params` twice (since I use `params` programmatically as well):

```
const customDefn: Defintion<{ test: "Hello World" }> = {
  params: { test: "Hello World" },
  handler: (dummy) => {
    console.log(dummy.test)
  }
}
```

Which can become cumbersome.

Comment: This is only possible in combination with a generic function. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLqabW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `this` can **not** be used to correlate properties within an object type. You can only use it to get the *"static"* type of a property.

In fact, using a stand-alone type, it is not possible to do any cross referencing between properties at all.

---

Instead, you can achieve this with a generic helper function.

```
interface Defintion<T> {
  params: T;
  handler: (dummy: T) => void; 
}

function createDefiniton<T>(definiton: Defintion<T>) {
  return definiton
}

createDefiniton({
  params: { test: "Hello World" },
  handler: (dummy) => {
    console.log(dummy.test)
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIRqMwD2IA8AKgHzIDeAUMsgA5xRwC2AzgFzKEDcVyAFnCAAmAG2jsAFIICujRgE92hAJTIAvKQBuOYIM7IKAXwoUYUkAmx5kCKBDiR0mEMDB4ixSRlAu87R1lwCEhVKalswKSgQZEEvZ1cQQ2MbOwc4nxBxUNp6JjZyZEhmMHYAIgAJCGFhHGQAdRwoYUFS5AMAGh5%20IVEoCWlZORV1ch5qBDxmHFEAOhqAc0kZeRmisCUeIwMlIA)